# AppleScript /JS document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: applescript, safari

I made a script to fill up a textbook in an internal webpage, but devs in my company changed the code so my code below don't work anymore

```
tell application "Safari" to tell window id theWINID to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('text-entry')[0].value=" & quoted form of myCaseNote in tab 1
```

here is the text field code of the page

[image]

I try many thing but I can't seems to change the text (in the picture demo "text I need to past")

any help would be very appreciate

```
<div lobid="##" data="[object Object]" casenotedata="[object Object]" caseid="5sd4sd-sd55sd-5sds5-sds5-sdsd55s" class="css-bzgzwc"><div class="note-input css-1d9ma27" data-cy="note-input"><div class="textarea-container"><div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div></div></div><div class="note-toolbar css-o3el1q" data-cy="note-toolbar"><div class="buttons-container"><button class="add-note-button" type="button">Apply</button></div></div></div>
<div class="note-input css-1d9ma27" data-cy="note-input"><div class="textarea-container"><div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div></div></div>
<div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div>
<div class="textarea-container"><div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div></div>
<div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div>
<div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div>
<textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea>
<div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div>
<span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span>
<div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div>
<div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div>
<div class="textarea-container"><div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div></div>
<div class="note-input css-1d9ma27" data-cy="note-input"><div class="textarea-container"><div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div></div></div>
<div class="note-toolbar css-o3el1q" data-cy="note-toolbar"><div class="buttons-container"><button class="add-note-button" type="button">Apply</button></div></div>
<div lobid="iTunes" data="[object Object]" casenotedata="[object Object]" caseid="bf4ecda0-113e-11ec-944e-9bd3d18184e9" class="css-bzgzwc"><div class="note-input css-1d9ma27" data-cy="note-input"><div class="textarea-container"><div class="form-textarea-container css-9db1eh"><div class="form-textbox"><div class="form-textarea focused"><textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea></div><span id="form-textarea-123_label" class="form-textbox-label" aria-hidden="true">Note</span></div></div></div></div><div class="note-toolbar css-o3el1q" data-cy="note-toolbar"><div class="buttons-container"><button class="add-note-button" type="button">Apply</button></div></div></div>
```

this work but it's seems that form-textarea-123 is changing all the time (the digits)

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('form-textarea-123').value = 'demo'" in current tab of window 1
    
end tell
```

the actual code

```
<textarea aria-invalid="false" id="form-textarea-123" name="note-input-224" aria-labelledby="form-textarea-123_label" aria-describedby=""></textarea>
```

This doesn't work neither :

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('form-textarea').innerText;" in current tab of window 1
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? Does `"document.getElementById('form-textarea-517').value = "foobar";"` (in proper context) work?

Comment: this work but the ID seems to change all the time, for instance now it's "form-textarea-155" I guess I won't be able to script that :(

Comment: Then I'd try using the **ByClassName** on `form-textarea form-textbox-entered` and if that does not work directly use it the parse its `.innerHTML` to get whatever `form-textarea-$number` is and then you should be able to make it work. Also, next time please post the **HTML** _code_ as text so we do not have to manually type out the class name or id to attempt to provide you with an answer.

Comment: do JavaScript "document.getElementById('form-textarea').innerHTML; = 'demo'" in current tab of window 1
this doesn't seems to work neither but I might have wrote in the wrong format? I had no luck with ByClassName

Comment: Try something like this: [https://paste.ee/p/XZh7E](https://paste.ee/p/XZh7E)

Comment: Here is the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ using it as a _handler_: [https://paste.ee/p/mCMLg](https://paste.ee/p/mCMLg)

Comment: that's work -- unfortunately in my case, it's add the text alright but then when I move the cursors the text vanish (I can only past the text manually using the cursors and CMD + V) but I'll still valid your answer if you post it. thanks a lot.

Comment: RE: "unfortunately in my case, it's add the text alright but then when I move the cursors the text vanish" --  I took the **HTML** _code_ in your questing and inserted into an **HTML** _document template_ and then opened it in **Safari**. Ran the _script_ and  it holds the _value_inserted even after moving the cursor.  There must be other things in play in the full _code_ of the document. At least it gets you a step closer and you should be able to continue to automate the process. I'll post it as an answer anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some *example* **AppleScript** *code* that will get you further along in the process of automating a full solution:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    tell its current tab of window 1
        
        set foo to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('form-textbox')[0].innerHTML;"
        
        set targetID to my getID(foo)
        
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & targetID & "').value = 'demo';"
        
    end tell
end tell


--  ## Handler ##

to getID(foo)
    set curTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " id="
    set foo to second text item of foo
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
    set foo to second text item of foo
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to curTID
    return foo
end getID
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>